# symfony2 SoapServer EntityManager injection in service

Tags: php, symfony, soap, code-injection, soapserver

I've got a problem with the native php SoapServer in symfony2.
The SoapServer uses a "UserService" Service-Class in symfony2, which should be instantiated with the symfony2 EntityManager injected so that I can get access to my "UserRepository".

To clarify:

Soap-Server:

```
$oSOAPServer = new \SoapServer('/path/to/wsdl');
$oSOAPServer->setClass("my\Namespace\UserService");
$oSOAPServer->handle();
```

Service:

```
use \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager as EntityManager;

class UserService
{
    protected $em;
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em) {
        $this->em = $em;
    }
...
```

Problem is: the SoapServer always returns an Internal Server Error.
The service itself works called in symfony2 directly.
Is it even possible to inject the EntityManager when called/instantiated by the SoapServer?

Thanks in advance!

Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `SoapServer::setClass()` you could use [`SoapServer::setObject()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapserver.setobject.php) and pass your service in:

```php
$oSOAPServer = new \SoapServer('/path/to/wsdl');
$oSOAPServer->setObject($container->get('my_service'));
$oSOAPServer->handle();
```

Implementing a soap server is documented in the Symfony documentation: [How to Create a SOAP Web Service in a Symfony2 Controller](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/web_services/php_soap_extension.html)

Also, if you only need a repository, don't inject the whole entity manager. Register your [repository as a service](http://blog.sznapka.pl/injecting-repositories-to-service-in-symfony2/) and inject it to your service.

Comment: Thank you, the setObject() seems to be what I was looking for.